# Can't load resource on first request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So this is really weird to me. I have this spring application I am writing and when I start the server and navigate to `http://localhost/ims/resources/index.html` for the first time it gives me the following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/ims] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:848)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

However if I refresh the page I don't have any problems. It only happens on the very first request. This is what my resource config looks like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mypackage.ims.web")
public class IMSAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("ims/resources/");
    }

    ....
}
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: What Spring MVC version are you on?

Comment: `<org.springframework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
  <spring-security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring-security.version>`

Comment: Can you post the rest of your servlet config, ie. the `IMSAppConfig` class?

Comment: It's all persistence config stuff, it doesn't do anything with the server config. Given the persistence information, I obviously don't want to post it.

Comment: Given the `DispatcherServlet` line that the logs are reporting, this is probably due to some `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` method that you override. Try debugging the initialization of the `DispatcherServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the base package scanning details and other details in context.xml file.
So that the configuration will be loaded once the project is deployed.

But in your case the package to search for the mapping urls is known to the spring only at the exectution time, So only after the program executes for the first time the spring maps down the urls and when you refresh (hit the server for the 2nd time) the url is found.

Comment: It seems to me that spring would have a better way to handle that right? I would think there would be a way to configure it completely in java and not require an xml file.